# Two ArrayList into a TreeMap

Tags: java

I've been searching StackOverflow for an answer regarding this issue.

Lets say I created two array lists,

arraylist1 holds Strings
arraylist2 holds Integers.

NOTE - I've added things into both of these arraylists. The values at each of the indices are related to the other value.

Meaning. lets say index 1 of arraylist1 = "Name". Index 1 of arraylist2 = 3, they are related in that I want to put things into a TreeMap (for the purpose of sorting by key) so that the treemap puts in the value ("Name", 3).

My problem -

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> mymap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
for(String s : arraylist1) {
     for(Integer v : arraylist2) {
          mymap.put(s, v);
```

The problem with this is if I added a bunch of random things for testing,

```
    arraylist1.add("h");
    arraylist1.add("i");
    arraylist1.add("e");
    arraylist2.add(1);
    arraylist2.add(3);
    arraylist2.add(2);
```

And I did the for loops, my result would come out to...

```
Key e Value: 2
Key h Value: 2
Key i Value: 2
```

Which solves the problem of sorting by key. However, the problem is that only the last value in the Integer arraylist, arraylist2, is being put into the TreeMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you want to iterate through both lists *at the same time* ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   map.put(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
}
```

As it currently stands, you're iterating over your second map for each key, and inserting the second list's values. Since a map only holds one value per key, your map results in the final value in your second list for each key.

As an aside, if these 2 values are intrinsically linked, perhaps create (or use [an existing](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)) `Pair` object to store these from the outset. The problem with using a standard map is that you can only store one value per key. e.g. you can't store `(A,B)` and `(A,C)`

Comment: Thank you. I actually solved the problem before even going back to this page. But to honor stackoverflow, I have to wait a few minutes to accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well fark, I was typing this in your deleted question before you deleted it, but didn't finish til after you deleted it:

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but consider:

- Creating a Game class that is in charge of the logic of the game.
- Creating Player objects that interact with the Game.
- When a Player wants to move, he calls Game's `move(Piece piece, Position position)` method, but with parameters.
- Have this method return a boolean, true if the move is valid and false if not...